# remove chars between variable and delimiter in a file

Tags: regex, bash

Hello i have the following file:

```
update_19.zip=10fcb39f96a83011a60
android_changelog_19.log=de34d340aa7d253dafa
android_manifest_19.xml=8b3173a122c222
```

I want to remote the text between _19 and =
Desired result:

```
update=10fcb39f96a83011a60
android_changelog=de34d340aa7d253dafa
android_manifest=8b3173a122c222
```

Note number 19 is variable

```
grep -P "(?<=_$number).*?(?==)"
```

How to select the group _$number as well and how to actually cut it off from the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the variable in a `sed` command.

```
sed "s/_$number[^=]*=/=/" filename
```

Comment: Use `-i` (edit files in place) to actually change your file's contents.